# windows ISO file showing a lock sign on it.that is why it is giving problems in making USB stick boot-able

Tags: boot, usb, windows

Because of this lock maybe that is why nothing helping me out in making a USB boot-able.I tried everything for making a windows ISO file to burn into a USB to patched,imaged to a USB that can be boot windows from a USB while starting up the PC and i can install windows with Ubuntu but nothing worked,now i will download win-7,maybe this will do something.

Comment: FYI after you install windows, you will have to reinstall grub from an ubuntu live disk or using bootrepair so have that ready.

Comment: i have an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit USB stick,,can that will help me.i installed Ubuntu from that USB.

Comment: Yes, that is what you will need after you install windows https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

It's showing a lock sign because you don't have permissions to use the file. Fix it by changing the ownership to you with:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /path/to/windows.iso
```

or you could just chmod it so everyone can use the file:

```
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/windows.iso
```

Comment: i am such an idiot...i even don't know how to write the path for that file..it is located in my home directory as xp.iso file..i write sudo chown $USER:$USER  /home/xp.iso and the message comes "chown: cannot access ‘/home/xp.iso’: No such file or directory"

Comment: If you are located in the same directory as the iso file you can skip the path. Try this -> "sudo chown $USER:$USER xp.iso"

Comment: i did it,,but still the lock sign is there..can now i use this .iso file for making a botable usb.

Comment: That's strange, have you also tried to chmod it with 777 permissions?

Comment: yes,i tried..sudo chmod 777 home/xp.iso
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,[sudo] password for oem: 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,chmod: cannot access ‘home/xp.iso’: No such file or directory

Comment: It's telling you an error message that the file you're trying to chmod isn't in that directory, I highly doubt that you have your file in 'home/xp.iso'. Try agian and set the path like this instead: /home/$USER/xp.iso

Comment: thanks a lot anyway.i will be familiar with these commands one day.